# Prove that $u$ and $v$ are independent if $u = 2x - 3y$ and $v = 3x - 4y$ where $v$ and $y$ are independent.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, independence

**QUESTION:** Prove that $u$ and $v$ are independentvariables if $u = 2x - 3y$ and $v = 3x - 4y$ where $v$ and $y$ are independent variables.

I writted $x = -4u + 3v$ and $y = -3u + 2v$, and then I assumed, by contradiction, that $u$ and $v$ are dependent variables, so i tried to write $u = f(v)$ and then with this get a contradiction like $x = g(y)$, but didn't get any.

I'm also a bit confused if i'm on the right track. If a could see a solution would really help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What are "independent variables" to you? Are you talking about independent random variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what "Independent variables" means, that's one of the things i'm trying to understand. Do you have a guess of what "Indepedent Variables" could mean?

Comment: It's hard to say without furhter context.